# h5py causes jupyter to crash in for loop

Tags: python, h5py

I am using a for loop to load arrays with different names into a h5py file. The goal is to load matlab files as python files from each independent folder, then to store all these loaded arrays into a h5py file.

Code:

```
with h5py.File("Filename.hdf5", 'w') as f:
    for i in Data_names:
        try:
            f.create_dataset(str(i), data = scipy.io.loadmat('./folder/' + str(i) + '/wantedfile.mat'))
        except IOError:
            pass
```

The code seems to work for the first 6 values of i, then starts to glitch. One of the error is a file save error and this also causes problems with opening any of my other notebooks.

Is the error in that the h5py file is too large? or is the problem an error with my for loop?

Comment: Can you share the entire error message? A way to reproduce the error would also be good. See: [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried a simple test with the 7th value in `Data_names`? Open a file with `h5py.File()` then enter `f.create_dataset()`, referencing `str(Data_names[6])` where you have `str(i)`. Likely culprits: 1) bad name in Data_names, 2) string conversion error on str(i), 3) error with the file referenced by `scipy.io.loadmat()` - either the file doesn't exist, is corrupted or or the data is bad.